# Is there any way I can send emoji in appium

Tags: java, appium, emoji

I have a test case and I wish to send emoji but I cannot locate the emoji elements using appium

Is there any way I can send emojis in a test case?

I write test cases in java

Comment: I haven't given it a try though. But if the app you are testing supports UTF-8 for emoji. Try sending "\ud83d\ude04" and see if it works.